# Where is Barry Allen of Earth-X?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the mega crossover of the CW-verse, on Earth-X, we see the evil counterparts of the Arrow (as Dark Arrow), Supergirl (as Overgirl), and counterparts of almost everyone except Barry Allen.

Well, Reverse Flash is present to fulfil a speedster's position. Is there any  mention about Earth-X's Barry Allen and/or his whereabouts?

Comment: Just assumption, but if Eobard Thawne is alive, we can assume that Reverse Flash won against Flash in the fight and killed him...

Comment: @NikhilEshvar he's Eobard of Earth-1. so that assumption won't hold. (And how he is still alive after being erased from history twice is yet to be seen)

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - There may not be a Barry Allen on Earth-X, and he may have never gotten powers if there were.

While there are (theoretically) doppelgangers of all people on the various Earths, that's not a guarantee. Notice that while there is a Supergirl on Earth-X, there is no Supergirl on Earth 1, and none of the other heroes of Earth 1 on Supergirl's Earth. Her Earth has no speedsters at all.

Also, when they do have parallel people, their lives are not always identical - note the Hunter Zolomon of Earth 1.

If there was no STAR Labs of Earth X, and no accelerator explosion, their Barry Allen, if he even existed, would not have gotten his powers, nor would any of the people who got theirs the same way.  Snart didn't get his via the explosion, so he's unaffected.

This would also explain why Ebobard Thawne is the one from Earth 1, and not from Earth-X's future - no Flash, no desire for future-Thawne-X to want to emulate him.

Answer (score 0):

In the canon animated web series that preceded "Crisis on Earth X," *Freedom Fighters: The Ray*. In it, the character **Blizkrieg** represents the Earth X version of Barry Allen. Voiced by Scott Whyte as opposed to Grant Gustin, he is the speedy member of the New Reichsmen. He is captured and incarcerated by the Freedom Fighters, explaining the need for him to be replaced by Reverse-Flash.
[image]